# Changing heroku repo for pre-existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I created a heroku repo some time ago for my rails app but deleted it because I was never using it. Now I have come to the point where I need to use heroku but I am encountering the following error:

`!  No such app as furious-mist-2295.` which was the old repo name, so it is clearly not pushing to the new stack I created.

This is what I was considering trying, but am concerned about causing unnecessary changes to my git repo.

`git remote rm origin`

`git remote add origin <URL to new heroku app>`

`git push -u origin master`

Comment: If heroku is the only remote you have and is called 'origin', this should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it can be done with the following commands

`git remote rm heroku`

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:new-application.git`

Which is quite a simple little fix. Seemed rather difficult without knowing beforehand that these commands existed.

`git remote -v` came in handy to double check which repos in git and heroku were being pushed and fetched.